# Mongoid migrate BigDecimal to Rails-Money

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm currently using `BigDecimal` type in a Mongoid 3 app. There are multiple Documents and each has multiple `BigDecimal` fields.  I'd like to migrate all the production data to type `Money` but keep the document field names the same. How should I do so without significant downtime?

One idea:

1. Create temporary fields in each Document with type `Money`
2. Convert data in existing fields into temporary field
3. Change original field type to Money
4. Copy data in temporary field to original field
5. Remove temporary field

Is there a better way?